# Why flag "begin" in leveldb WAL is defined as ptr == slice.data()?

Tags: c++, leveldb, wal

This code is in leveldb to get the type of fragment type in WAL

```
Status Writer::AddRecord(const Slice& slice) {
   RecordType type; 
    // Why not defined as left == slice.size();
    const bool begin = (ptr == slice.data());
    const bool end = (left == fragment_length);
    if (begin && end) {
      type = kFullType;
    } else if (begin) {
      type = kFirstType;
    } else if (end) {
      type = kLastType;
    } else {
      type = kMiddleType;
    }

}
```

Why not defined as `left == slice.size()?` It looks more simpler?

Comment: `begin` is `true` when `ptr` points to the begin of `slice`. Your suggestion `left == slice.size()` does something else

Comment: Are the two equivalent? "left" represents the amount of data in "record" that has not been sliced. When it equals "slice.size()", it means that "record" has not been sliced, indicating the first execution of the while loop. I believe its meaning is equivalent to "ptr = slice.data()", and even clearer.